# CiviMail report not showing proper data after upgrade

Tags: wordpress, civimail, upgrade

I have recently upgraded CIVICRM to 4.7.27 and my wordpress version is 4.9.1. Before upgrade civimail report was showing proper data for example "Unique Opens", "Total Opens", etc. But now it's showing 0 value. I have checked all permission on files and folder and its default as

```
d -exec chmod 755

f -exec chmod 644
```

Please help me ASAP.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wordpress but we had this issue once after making different changes in Drupal and it ended up being a caching issue. Can you clear your CiviCRM caches and see if it fixes it?

Comment: Yes i have already clear cache.

Comment: Not yet resolve problem after clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Arvind,

Are you facing problem in reports or when you view mailings?

Comment: Problem has resolved, It was file's permission issue. Thans all of you!

Comment: Please remember that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. To ask for clarification on a post, you should leave a comment such as this one. If you are new to Stack Exchange, I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], as standards and practices here are particular.